# Jenkins pipeline ends with success but without executing any stage

Tags: jenkins

Hello i am trying to create a pipeline but when launch it it ends with success but without executing any stage !

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stage('Build') {
      steps{
        dir('C:/Users/user/Downloads/devopss-main/devopss-main') {
                bat 'mvn clean install'
      }}
    }
        
    stage("Sonar") {
      steps {
        dir('C:/Users/user/Downloads/devopss-main/devopss-main') {
                bat 'mvn sonar:sonar'
      }}
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrLYq.png)

Comment: Please let me know if my solution works for you. In the future it would be beneficial to include the Jenkins version ( and the versions of any relevant changes plugins )

Comment: Do you have the declarative pipeline plugin installed

Answer (score 5):

## Solution

First make sure you have the [Declarative : Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-model-definition/) plugin installed.

After installation you need to modify your script.  When you write your pipeline declaratively as opposed to imperatively ( colloquially referred to as a *scripted pipeline* ) you need to all wrap `stage`'s in a `stages` block.

> However, your pipeline does not even work in Jenkins 2.x.  The pipeline will throw an error as it's currently configured so I'm not sure how your pipeline even finished successfully. With these modifications your pipeline will work

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps{
                dir('C:/Users/user/Downloads/devopss-main/devopss-main') {
                    bat 'mvn clean install'
                }       
            }
        }
            
        stage("Sonar") {
            steps {
                dir('C:/Users/user/Downloads/devopss-main/devopss-main') {
                    bat 'mvn sonar:sonar'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```